# Woocommece - List product categories that also match product taxonomy

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a list of products that site under product categories that work well. I also have CPT setup of 'shop_location' so here we can list different shop locations.

I want to show the product categories (that have products) for a specfic taxonomy of shop_location.

So e.g. I want to show all product categories (with products), for the shop_location which is equals to London.

I have tried the following but this is not firing correctly, could someone please help me. Thank you!

```
<?php
$orderby = 'name';
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false ;
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'shop_location',
            'terms'     => array( $category->slug ),
            'name'     => 'london',
        )
    )   
);

$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );

if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '

<ul>';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        echo '

<li>';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        echo $category->name;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>


';
}
   ?>
```

Comment: `'field' => 'london',` - that makes no sense whatsoever. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters: _"field (string) – Select taxonomy term by. Possible values are ‘term_id’, ‘name’, ‘slug’ or ‘term_taxonomy_id’. Default value is ‘term_id’."_ - this specifies _by what property_ you want to select the taxonomy.

Comment: Apologies that was meant to say 'name'. Could you please help why this isn't working? been on this for hours I cant find how to do this

Comment: I don't get your description of the actual setup yet. `shop_location` is what now? A taxonomy? Or a custom post type?

Comment: shop_location is a taxonomy that we've added, so we bascially want to show all categories that are also selected by 'london' in the 'shop_location' taxonomy

Comment: `get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );` - with that first parameter, you are saying that you want terms out of the `product_cat` taxonomy. But now with the arguments you are saying, you want to apply an additional tax_query to those? So your `product_cat` terms would themselves by divided by a further sub-category named `shop_location`? And where would the actual CPT come into play now?

Comment: All I want is to show all categorys that are in product category, that also have the taxonomy selected of 'london' which is in the 'shop_location' taxonomy

Comment: _"shop_location is a taxonomy that we've added"_ - add _to_ what? I really don't get your setup here, it sounds as if you wanted the terms _themselves_, that are in one taxonomy (product_cat), to be categorized by _another_ taxonomy? (Is that kind of setup even _possible_ in WP?)